# FXMessageBox in Ruby

Tags: ruby, fxruby

I'm working with FXRuby, and I'm trying to figure out how to have an error dialog box, similar to

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

in Java. The closest equivalent I have found is `FXMessageBox.error`, however usage of this method is seemingly impossible. The documentation specifies the follow parameters in order, `FXMessageBox.error(owner, opts, caption, message)`. I have tried this so far

```
app = FXApp.new

FXMessageBox.error(app, nil, 'Error', 'Error!')
```

However, it gives me the error

> Wrong arguments for overloaded method 'FXMessageBox.error'.

When I try to do

```
FXMessageBox.error(app, FXMessageBox::MBOX_OK, 'Error', 'Error!')
```

I get

> FXMessageBox::create: trying to create window before creating parent window.

How do I create the requested Error box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MBOX_OK` is required, as you said. If you create the application before you run it, you should see the error dialog. Here is a working example:

```
require 'fox16'
include Fox

app = FXApp.new
app.create
FXMessageBox.error(app, MBOX_OK, 'Error', 'Error!')
app.run
```

Comment: That was perfect! Thank you so much.